# Determining whether or not a new observation in a time series is significantly different from past observations

Tags: time-series, statistical-significance, confidence-interval, data-transformation, differences

**Edit: The question is whether or not this methodology is valid, assuming both underlying distributions are normal.**

Data:
A time series of difference data (e.g. Distribution 1 value - Distribution 2 value), where higher values are better.

Goal:
To determine if a newly observed difference is significantly higher or lower than the 30 period moving average trend.

Method:
Compute the mean and sample standard deviation of the past 30 observed differences, and do a simple z-test of significance on the new data point (I compare the out of sample number to the mean and variance of the past data).
This also gives me a time series of the z-scores.

Problem:
I feel that this is too simple a solution and that I'm missing something important (e.g. I think by doing this I've assumed that the two underlying distributions are normal and that I can sum them to create a new normal distribution).

Answer (score 0):

For one thing, if your data is autocorrelated your z-test would have wrong degrees of freedom --the observations used to compute average and standard deviation would not be independent.

Perhaps you could fit a time series model and do something similar with innovations?

Comment: Yep, I knew I was missing something:
1. I'm treating the data as though it is independent (bad because it's not).
2. Leading to fake significance (bad)
3. Also I'm doing a weird confidence test

Back to the drawing board!